# Geolocation using IP

Tags: geolocation, ip, freegeoip

I have been trying to find a tool to locate my position using my computer `ip`.

I have tried some web tools such as `http://geoiplookup.net/`and `https://geoiptool.com/` and some developer tools like `freegeoip.net`, in which I'm more interested.

the fact is: geolocation is **way off** in all of them, at least where I'm located (South America, Brazil), *all pointing to the same wrong location*.

why is it so?

I have tried this piece of code:

```
    send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
    r = requests.get(send_url)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    lat = j['latitude']
    lon = j['longitude']

    return (lat, lon)
```

but since it uses a wrong `ip` it returns some strange `lat/lgn`, miles away from me.

1) can I pass my exact `ip` as an argument in the code above?

2) is there any other tool for finding out my precise `lat, lng`, other than `googlemaps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP address geolocation is relatively less accurate compare to other geolocation methods such as GPS or WiFi MAC address. The reason is due to frequent reallocate of IP address by ISP.

Reference: http://www.geolocation.com

Back to your questions.

1) The API should auto detect your IP address and return you the estimated location

2) You could not find your precise lat and longitude without enable the GPS

Answer (score 0):

Try the services of http://geoip-db.com

A small jQuery example to retrieve location, country, city, lat, lon, ip and state:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GEOIP DB - jQuery example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <div>IP: <span id="IPv4"></span>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_name);
            $('#state').html(location.state);
            $('#city').html(location.city);
            $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
            $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);  
        }
    });     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```